# how to bind combobox and web service in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have a combo box and a web service. I want to call web service and then when I open my combo I see the values the are in my web service.My code did not work.Can anybody help me?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string firstParam = "1";

    DataSet ds2 = ws1.Automation_H022_MamooriyatSaati_View(firstParam, secondParam, thirdParam);
    this.GridView1.DataSource = ds2;
    foreach (System.Data.DataTable table1 in ds1.Tables)
    {
        foreach (DataRow dr in table1.Rows)
        {
            cmbox.DataTextField = "Tp_Place";
            cmbox.DataValueField = "Lg_Personality";
            cmbox.DataBind();
            cmbox.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("", "1"));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding not adding anything to the `cmbox` in the `foreach (DataRow dr in table1.Rows)`. And even if you did the next loop would overwrite it.
You need to set the datasource for the ComboBox in the same way you set the GridView.

If there is more than one table in `ds1` and you want both tables to be visible in the combobox then you need to merge those two (or more) tables first and then bind them as a single source of data.

```
DataSet ds2 = ws1.Automation_H022_MamooriyatSaati_View(firstParam, secondParam, thirdParam);
this.GridView1.DataSource = ds2;

cmbox.DataSource = ds1.Tables[0];
cmbox.DataTextField = "Tp_Place";
cmbox.DataValueField = "Lg_Personality";
cmbox.DataBind();
cmbox.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("", "1"));
```